# Are DOM elements preceding a <script> tag guaranteed to exist before the script runs?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Does the HTML spec guarantee that DOM elements appearing before a `<script>` tag are present before the content of that script is executed (and can be manipulated by that script)?

This works in all browsers I've tested, but I'm not sure whether it's legal:

```html
<main hidden>Hello, world</main>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('main').hidden = false;  // no error thrown
</script>
```

I know that the script [will execute immediately, blocking parsing,](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-script-element) unless it has the `async` or `defer` attributes.

But does the parsing up until this point guarantee that the prior elements are in the DOM and ready to be manipulated, or is it safest to wait for `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: Yes completely guaranteed, with one exception. A prior script could have already removed the element from  the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it will run just after parsing the previous node. You can use even `document.write` function to feed the parser with code.

As you can try below, it can even close tags. It directly feeds the output from `document.write()` to the parser.

```html
Foo
<script>
  document.write("<strong>bar</strong>")
</script>

<em>something
<script>
  document.write("weird</em>")
</script>
here.
```

You can access the DOM in scripts even when the loading is in progress, but I would personally avoid it. As you can see below, element that was not yet closed can be accessed.

```html
This works:

<em id="foo">foo</em>
<script>
  document.write(document.getElementById("foo"))
</script>

<hr />

<em id="unclosed">unclosed element
<script>
  document.write(document.getElementById("unclosed"))
</script>
</em>
```

But avoid long-running scripts, because the parser (and therefore rendering) will stop and it can be unpleasant if the scripts does its work for few seconds.

In this example, you can see that you can hide, **and even remove**, the element even just after the opening tag:

```html
<p id="toHide">
  <script>
    document.getElementById("toHide").remove()
  </script>
  
  This is hidden.
</p>

This is not hidden.
```

Comment: Yeah, there are just a few elements I'd like to show or hide in JS as early as possible; everything else happens after DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: Then, I think it is absolutely fine, it you do that for enabling the content depending on JavaScript support.

Comment: See the last snippet, it manipulates the element just after its opening tag, so even its content will not appear in the DOM. You can also manipulate styles, classes etc.